# java - The method enableLogging() is undefined for the type ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder

Tags: java, android, eclipse, methods

I'm getting following error with the current code.
It says "The method enableLogging() is undefined for the type ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder"

enableLogging() is underlined in eclipse.

```
public static void initImageLoader(Context context) { 
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
               context).threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2) .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory() 
.discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator()) .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO).enableLogging().build();
               // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
               ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
}
}
```

Comment: If you're using a non-standard library, please indicate which one and provide a link. Looks like you're using Android Universal Image Loader.

Comment: Im using this library https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 5):

`writeDebugLogs()` [was](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/commit/9c266bdc8c023c0c6d7a119bfc9f8ccc965b337d#L2R516) introduced to replace `enableLogging()`. Use it instead.

Comment: This looks to be the issue. The developer should have deprecated `enableLogging()` and left it in, but it got yanked.

Comment: thanks for the resource but i dont really get how to change the code. Appreciate any help

Comment: @D.M You really need to spend some time learning basic Java before you tackle a more complicated project like this. You won't be able to make any progress until you have the fundamentals.